# Regarding flow initiation

Tags: corda

If I have 3 participants and I need to make sure that the contract can only be initiated by, say PartyA. Should I be including this participant as a variable in the respective flow? Because anyhow we'll be initiating the flow from that participant's node right!?

Answer (score 0):

- You can hardcode the value inside the `Initiator` flow:

```java
if (getOurIdentity().equals(CordaX500Name.parse("O=Initiator,L=London,C=GB"))) {
}
```

- But the above step is not enough, the resopnders to your flow don't know (and don't trust) whether you made sure that the initiator is a certain entity or not. So, inside the `Responder` you must also check the initiator:

```java
if (otherPartySession.getCounterparty()
        .equals(CordaX500Name.parse("O=Initiator,L=London,C=GB"))) {    
}
```

Btw, a better option than hardcoding the value, would be to use CorDapp configuration files; read about it in my article [here](https://blog.b9lab.com/how-to-create-a-cordapp-configuration-file-ef79581b9e3-ef79581b9e3c).

On a side note, remember that it's the responsibility of the responding node to implement (i.e. write) a responder flow; just because you gave some node your CorDapp (so they can run the responder), doesn't mean they'll use it; they can create their own version of the responder flow (read [here](https://www.corda.net/blog/corda-flow-responder-wrong-assumptions/)). That's why the check must happen in both `Initiator` and `Responder` flows.